# Is there a way of implementing a composite primary key with varying fields in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, primary-key, c#, composite-types

Here is the information about my development environment:

-Mongodb 3.0.0

-Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013

-.NET Framework 4.5

We are trying to design some MongoDB collections at work that are associated with each in a complex way.

Speed performance is very important because we will deal with millions of records.

In any case, here is a business requirement.

Let's say I have health care policies that vary across provincial states in the United States.

Along, with concern such as provincial states in the US, I may need to consider certain exceptional cases such as whether the person is a senior citizen, sex, health history, chronic illnesses, etc.

The Exceptional cases really vary in their values.

Let's say we have a Person Model.

Person

_id: ObjectId

FirstName: String

LastName: String

ProvincialStateOfResidenceID: String

ExceptionCasesDocRefs: Array[ ExceptionCasesID ]

The ProvincialStateOfResidence field will always have a value.

The ExceptionCasesDocRefs array could be empty Or It could contain multiple IDs

Let's have a HealthPolicy Model that will always have a value for ProvincialStateOfResidenceID field.

HealthPolicy

ProvincialStateOfResidenceID: String

ExceptionCasesDocRefs: Array[ ExceptionCasesID ]

PolicyCost:  Double

PolicyDuration: Double

RequiredHealthEvaluation: Double

blah.blah.....

blah......

We also have an ExceptionCasesReference Collection that will contain values like the following:

ExceptionCasesReference

ExceptionCasesID : ObjectID

ExceptionCase: Name

ExceptionCaseDescription: String

I need to somehow make the following into a composite primary key:

ProvincialStateOfResidenceID: String

ExceptionCasesDocRefs: Array[ ExceptionCasesID ]

It is problematic to make the above into a composite primary key because ExceptionCasesDocRefs can have values that range from NULL to a many ExceptionCasesID.

Is there a way of modelling the aforementioned MongoDB Collection(s) in such a way that speed performance is upheld?